# How should I use OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier with react-leaflet?

Tags: javascript, react-leaflet

I am rewriting an existing web app to a React app. In the original, [leaflet](https://leafletjs.com/) is used for maps, along with [OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier](https://github.com/jawj/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier)
 to create a distinction between map markers. In the new app, I'm using [react-leaflet](https://react-leaflet.js.org/). All the other plugins used are available to react, but I want to create a leaflet custom component for OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier. I am a bit out of my depth with creating this component.

Ideally, I'd like to call the component like this in the React render loop.

```
return (
  <Map>
    <Spiderfy >
      <Marker>
        <Popup>
        </Popup>
      </Marker>
      <Marker>
        <Popup>
        </Popup>
      </Marker>
    </Spiderfy>
  </Map>
  )
```

The OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier example shows an instance of the object being created, an event listener is added to the map, and all the Markers are added to the OMS instance. I've tried squeezing this into a ReactLeaflet class but had no success so far.

```
class _Spiderfy extends MapLayer {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.oms = null
    }

    createLeafletElement ({children, leaflet: {map, ...props}})  {
        let newLayer = L.featureGroup()
        this.oms = new OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier(map);

        var popup = new L.Popup();
        this.oms.addListener('click', function(marker) {
            popup.setContent(marker.desc);
            popup.setLatLng(marker.getLatLng());
            map.openPopup(popup);
        });

        this.oms.addListener('spiderfy', function(markers) {
            map.closePopup();
          });

        return newLayer
    }
}

export default withLeaflet(_Spiderfy);
```

This is the wrapper I currently have. It renders the children (all the markers and their popups), but the event listener doesn't execute when the map is clicked. I also don't know how to get the Marker objects from the children list and add them to the oms instance.

Does anyone have some advice to create this class or some other library which does something very similar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You was close enough, here is an updated component version which demonstrates how to integrate [`OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier-Leaflet`](https://github.com/jawj/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier-Leaflet) into [React-Leaflet](https://react-leaflet.js.org/)

```
class Spiderfy extends MapLayer {

  createLeafletElement(props) {
    const { map } = props.leaflet;
    this.oms = this.createOverlappingMarkerSpiderfier(map);
    const el = L.layerGroup();
    this.contextValue = { ...props.leaflet, layerContainer: el };
    return el;
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    super.componentDidMount();
    this.leafletElement.eachLayer(layer => {
      if (layer instanceof L.Marker) {
        this.oms.addMarker(layer);
      }
    });
  }

  createOverlappingMarkerSpiderfier(map) {
    const oms = new window.OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier(map);
    oms.addListener("spiderfy", markers => {
      markers.forEach(m => m.closePopup())//force to close popup 
      if (this.props.onSpiderfy) this.props.onSpiderfy(markers);
    });
    oms.addListener("unspiderfy", markers => {
      if (this.props.onUnspiderfy) this.props.onUnspiderfy(markers);
    });
    oms.addListener("click", marker => {
      if (this.props.onClick) this.props.onClick(marker);
    });
    return oms;
  }
}

export default withLeaflet(Spiderfy);
```

The list of missing parts:

- initialization from markers list via `OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier.addMarker` method
- event handlers implementation

And [here is a demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-fro5up) for your reference

Comment: Is it possible to work with FeatureGroup which is commonly used for panning [like so](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-zmxau9?file=Map.js)? It currently errors out.

Comment: Hey @LouisChristopher, the error seems to be caused by `overlapping-marker-spiderfier-leaflet`, maybe you could raise a separate question in this regard?

Comment: Sure, thanks for the quick response, I've posted a [separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64507047/how-to-use-leaflets-featuregroup-with-overlappingmarkerspiderfier-in-react-leaf). :)

Comment: is it possible to use it with the latest react-leaflet v3? 
`Error in /~/Spiderfy.js (9:40)
Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null` 
thanks