# How to use Leaflet's FeatureGroup with OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier in react-leaflet?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I'm having trouble integrating [OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier](https://github.com/jawj/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier-Leaflet) with [React-Leaflet](https://react-leaflet.js.org/) and using [FeatureGroup](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/en/components#featuregroup) for panning on the map. FeatureGroups are really [useful](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#featuregroup-getbounds) when you have complicated panning logic.

Here is a [plain JS demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-ajz5oq). The markers spiderfy and the pan button works with no issues.

Here is the [react-leaflet demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-zmxau9?file=Map.js). The panning will fail with the following error if spiderfy is enabled/checked in the UI. This is based on this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55521219/how-should-i-use-overlappingmarkerspiderfier-with-react-leaflet/55553935).

`layer.getLatLng is not a function`

I think the problem is that with regular JS, I can add the markers array to both `oms` and the `featureGroup` imperatively but with React-leaflet, I don't see how I can achieve the same result.

Is the error because `<Spiderfy>` layer does not have a `getLatLng` function for some reason even though I am extending the [MapLayer](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/en/components#maplayer).

I'm unsure of what needs fixing, the JS version seems to work so the OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier library likely doesn't need changes. It could be a React-leaflet specific problem/limitation that can possibly be fixed with a custom FeatureGroup/MapLayer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the error

> layer.getLatLng is not a function

occurs since FeatureGroup.getBounds function expects underlying layers to implement either `getBounds` or `getLatLng` methods which is not the case with custom [`Spiderfy.js` component](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-zmxau9?file=Spiderfy.js) where container (`layerContainer` prop) is of `L.layerGroup` type.

One option to consider would be to refactor `Spiderfy.js` component:

- abandon `L.layerGroup` as a layer container
- since a recent React version is utilized (`16.8` or above) replace `ES6 class` component with function to implement `Spiderfy` component

`Spiderfy.js` component

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { withLeaflet, MapLayer, useLeaflet } from "react-leaflet";
import L from "leaflet";
import "overlapping-marker-spiderfier-leaflet/dist/oms";

function Spiderfy(props) {
  const { map, layerContainer } = useLeaflet();
  const oms = new window.OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier(map);
  oms.addListener("spiderfy", (markers) => {
    markers.forEach((m) => m.closePopup()); //force to close popup
    if (props.onSpiderfy) props.onSpiderfy(markers);
  });
  oms.addListener("unspiderfy", (markers) => {
    if (props.onUnspiderfy) props.onUnspiderfy(markers);
  });
  oms.addListener("click", (marker) => {
    if (props.onClick) props.onClick(marker);
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    layerContainer.eachLayer((layer) => {
      if (layer instanceof L.Marker) {
        oms.addMarker(layer);
      }
    });
  }, [oms,layerContainer]);

  return <div>{props.children}</div>;
}

export default withLeaflet(Spiderfy);
```

This way `FeatureGroup.getBounds` function should return the expected result, identical to provided in [plain JS demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-ajz5oq).

[**Forked** example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-v4zetr)

Comment: Is the reason why we create a new OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier instance on every render because we have no way to tell if the props.children have been modified or not?

Answer (score 1):

As [Vadim correctly pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64516378/1872840), `L.layerGroup` does not implement `getBounds`.

The main drawback of abandoning a layerGroup is that components that are not children of the Spiderfy Component are also spiderfied as it uses the `layerContainer`

- See this [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-jnmfp5?file=Spiderfy.js). If you look at the console log, the `markerCount` variable is 4 even though there are only three markers as Spiderfy's children.

Looking at Leaflet's documentation, we can use [L.featureGroup](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#featuregroup) instead of a layerGroup as it's simply an extension of the layerGroup.

`const el = L.featureGroup([], this.getOptions(props));`

- [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-lodgb6-spider-class?file=Spiderfy.js), you can see that the `markerCount` variable is 3 and not 4

Depending on your use case, nesting feature groups like this won't be a problem. Optionally you can take a look at [SubGroups](https://github.com/ghybs/Leaflet.FeatureGroup.SubGroup)